# iOS set date to MM//DD/YY 00:00:00

Tags: ios, date

I know there's a few questions already on this but I keep running into the same error regardless of what I do to my code. I am working in the simulator, I have location set to my long/lat. When I try to convert the current date to zero hours, minutes, seconds I always get this result:

```
2015-07-10 08:53:19.868 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[2184:7462272] Today at start of day:2015-07-10 04:00:00 +0000
```

Here's my code:

```
NSDate* today = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    NSCalendar* currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [currentCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:today];

    NSInteger thisMonth = [dateComponents month];
    NSInteger thisDay = [dateComponents day];
    NSInteger thisYear = [dateComponents year];

    NSDateComponents* dayComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dayComponents setDay:thisDay];
    [dayComponents setMonth:thisMonth];
    [dayComponents setYear:thisYear];


    NSDate* todayAtMidnight = [currentCalendar dateFromComponents:dayComponents];

    NSLog(@"Today at start of day:%@", todayAtMidnight);
```

Even if add

```
[dayComponents setHour:0]; the hour still comes out as 4.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the beginning of today you can use

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                                           fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

NSLog(@"date %@", [calendar dateFromComponents:components]);
```

Make sure you have the correct timezone

Comment: Upvoted everyone but took yours because I was already using date components. Thanks for the assist everyone.

Answer (score 1):

`2015-07-10 04:00:00 +0000` is UTC, not your local timezone.

To display it in your local timezone, use an NSDateFormatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSLog([dateFormatter stringFromDate:todayAtMidnight]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSDateFormatter` as follow because system timezone is UTC:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate * curDate = [formatter dateFromString:[NSDate date]];
```

Then you'll get `2015-07-10 00:00:00`.

Comment: How can you give NSDate format to DateFromString method ?